# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor while using pip command in python

Tags: command-line, python, pip

It shows the following error when I tried to upgrade pip or install new packages using pip in cmd. I've uninstalled and reinstalled python but the problem still exists. My current python version is 3.7.3, I am running it on Windows 10 platform. This error message shows:

> OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

How to fix this? and what causes this error.

The error message is:

```
C:\Users\ELCOT>python -m pip install -upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
  OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

C:\Users\ELCOT>pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "c:\users\elcot\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
  OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: My understanding is that `Bad File Descriptor` is a generic OS error which means there was a general issue when handling the file for reading or writing. In your case, it seems plausible the file is locked for some reason and that may be causing an issue (based on the error you're receiving).

Comment: Is there any solution for it..I have found that it shows error in the pip._internal file...I uninstalled and installed python several times but it didn't create script folder and pip files.I did custom installation with automatic pip installation but it didn't install pip.I have also tried python 3.5 ,3.6 and also I downloaded get-pip.py but nothing helped me .The same error comes again.suggest me some solution

Comment: I am uncertain what the exact error might be caused by. Based on your post, however, I might recommend completely uninstalling Python (again) and then reinstalling it somewhere *other* than either `AppData` or `Program Files`/`Program Files (x86)` (e.g. try installing it in a folder such as `C:\Programs\Python37`, for example). Just remember not to use any spaces in the path. If that doesn't solve the issue, there may be some other issue with your system.

Answer (score 0):

I think lately (last 3 years or so) Windows updated some security setting, maybe to fight with Ransomware, so the program we write , for example , python program, can only read/write files inside of C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents folder.

I used to create a special working folder as C:\working and do all the coding thing for fun, now the program is no longer working due to this security update. Moving exactly the same program into C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents, then it is working as always.